# How to enable flash in Selenium with headless chrome

Tags: java, flash, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to automate some interactions with our flash app as part of our CI process.  I'm running into troubles with enabling flash when running chrome headlessly (via xvfb-run) with Selenium Standalone Server.  I've done a lot of searching, but thus far haven't come up with anything that works.

I'm currently using this, but am open to switching to different versions if there's a known working config somewhere...

- Selenium Standalone Server 3.11
- Chromedriver 2.33
- Chrome 65.0.3325.181
- Java 8

When I first got this started I would get a warning on the page saying I needed to enable Adobe Flash Player.  I got "past" that message by using the following from https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/enable-flash-player-on-chrome-62-while-running-selenium-test:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("headless");

    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
    prefs.put("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);
    prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
    // Enable Flash for this site
    prefs.put("PluginsAllowedForUrls", "ourapp.com");
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("ourapp.com");
```

When loading our app, the page now gives a slightly different message which I haven't been able to get past.  Is there a way to get around this, or is there any other way to enable Flash by default?

[Restart Chrome to enable Adobe Flash Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXDNz.png)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a coworker for pointing out this post indicating that plugins don't work in headless chrome. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/headless-dev/flash%7Csort:date/headless-dev/mC0REfsA7vo/rKAZdRrCCQAJ

Fortunately in my case I was already using xvfb as a virtual display, so removing the "headless" argument from my ChromeOptions was all I needed to get everything running.

**EDIT***

While true that I did not need to run in headless mode while using xvfb, I ended up finding that the real 'solution' (more of a workaround) to my problem was to upload a custom chrome profile into my docker image.  Doing so allowed me to set all the preferences I needed, and none of the code posted in the original post is required.  Would much prefer to achieve this programatically, but this at least gets me what I need for now.  Figured I'd post in case someone else runs into this in the future..